# How to reference other values in JSON without copy pasting?

Tags: c++, json, jsonschema, jsoncpp, nlohmann-json

So I was wondering how can I actually use try to minimize me repeating a particular value and I could just refer to a different key present somewhere in the JSON.

For example in data.json

```
"loggingFile": "archive.txt"
...
...
"someKey": [
    {
        "name": "Gidrah",
        "loggingFile": // Now refer back to top-level loggingFile
    }
]
```

I have tried to search for it online and [found here](https://redocly.com/docs/resources/ref-guide/) that there is something about references in JSOn and it could be used as if:

```
{
    "schema": {
        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Pet"
    }
}
```

But this does not work for me as nlohmann::json that I am using in C++ identifies it as an object rather than the string that I need to use.

Comment: The "something about references" is a proposal how to indicate references in json/yaml and it is unknown what implements it if anything. Your question however leaves dim what you do and why. IOW why you can't have "archive.txt" repeated? Is it better to repeat GUID like "94e210f7-bdbb-480c-863f-6955e1fe4ffe"?  Also it is unclear what you expect as outcome, what you actually get and how it differs from what you expected.

Comment: You have to write your reference resolver, but unclear how you want to use it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, JSONSchema files are preprocessed to replace references of the form `{"$ref": ...}`. If you want something similar, you have to implement it yourself. You will need to do a recursive walk of the file and replace any references you see. nlohmann::json has support for JSON Pointer, which should suffice. Also take care to avoid introducing loops into your data structure.

Alternatively, consider switching to YAML where this feature is baked into the file format. `&anchor` marks a node for reuse, and `*anchor` inserts a reference to the original node.

```yaml
loggingFile: &loggingFile archive.txt

someKey:
  - name: Gidrah
    loggingFile: *loggingFile
```